# removal of DC offset using highpass fft filter

Tags: matlab, filter, fft

I have some data that has a DC offset and might have a slight slope. The signal are two main peaks (similar to a gaussian) followed by decaying oscillations.

I tried the following code, but this does not remove a DC offset - it removes a curved offset (sinus?).

```
function [ filteredData ] = fourierFilter( inputData )

factor = 8;
N = 1024*factor;
dataRaw = zeros([1 N]);
dataStart = N/2 - round(size(inputData,2)/2);
indices = dataStart:(dataStart+size(inputData,2))-1;
dataRaw(indices) = inputData;

% transform to fourierspace
fourierSpectrum = (fftshift(fft(dataRaw)));

% add filter
delta = 1*factor/4;
indicesfftfilter = N/2-delta:N/2+delta;
fourierSpectrum(indicesfftfilter) = 0;

% back transform
filteredData = real(ifft(ifftshift(fourierSpectrum)));
filteredData = (filteredData(indices));
```

Here an example of the data (blue) and a filtered curve (red) with `delta = 3*factor/4`

[image]

Comment: Can you post a plot of the resulting filtered signal?  What happens when delta = 1 or delta = 0?

Comment: You might try the beta Signal Processing site, http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Matlab's `detrend` might help here: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/detrend.html

Comment: I added some sample data. As one can see, the peaks have a rather low frequency. High frequency is only due to noise. The curve is slighty tilded.

Answer (score 6):

To remove DC, you can just type:

```
inputData_DCRemoved = inputData - mean(inputData);
```

Answer (score 1):

A low-frequency blocking filter isn't the best way to deal with this.  You are probably getting some ringing due to the harsh edges in Fourier space, setting some amplitudes to zero while leaving the adjacent ones as they are.

Better: fit a line or low-order polynomial to the data, and then subtract it.

EDIT: Ah, now that I see an example of your data... First, you want to mark that peak as "bad data", and do a low-order polynomial fit to the rest.  I don't see any slope, or very slight slope, so a constant (zero-order) fit might do well. Subtract this constant or polynomial from the original data (forgetting about any "bad" data) and there's your result.  None of this is easier in Fourier space.

Weighted poly fit routines exist in all the widely used interactive mathematical programs, including Matlab.

Comment: The high peak at the beginning tilts the linear fit and thus defines a wrong offset.

Answer (score 0):

A high-pass filter is just removing the slow-changing parts of the signal. The slowest part of the signal is the mean of it, so I would just try to subtract it from the signal...

Otherwise, you can take your signal and smooth it and then subtract it:

```
lowpasssignal = smooth(signal,100);
signal_highpass = signal - lowpasssignal;
```

This is the pragmatic approach.